# Hover Alpha mask overflow div with image

Tags: html, css

So I've created a scalable div with two images within it. The div with the images scale fine and in regards to font size scalability I know I can use media queries. However the hover alpha mask overflows and I do not know how to make it 100% to the image div. I hope I'm explaning myself properly. In any case [here is the live JS](https://jsfiddle.net/r469x2at/19/), the HTML,

```
         <div class="My-Gems">
                 <h2 class="Second-Header">Latest Works</h2>

                <div class="item item-type-double">
                    <div class="item-img">
                        <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/8safbuqmf/Money_Matters_Logo_gif.png " style="width:100%;" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <a class="item-hover">
       <div class="item-info">
           <div class="mycell">
        <div class="date">Branding</div>           
        <div class="line"></div>            
        <div class="headline">Money Matters</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
     <div class="mask"></div>
   </a>


                </div>
                <div class="item item-type-double"> 
                    <div class="item-img">
                        <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/wrpgkar0n/Metaphon_Fitness.png" style="width:100%;"/>
                    </div>
                    <a class="item-hover" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S74yj5rnvAo" target="_blank">
       <div class="item-info">
           <div class="mycell">
        <div class="date">Events</div>           
        <div class="line"></div>            
        <div class="headline">Metaphon Fitness</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
           </div></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
   </a>


                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of my-gems-->
```

And the CSS:

```
.My-Gems {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h2.Second-Header {
    color: black;
    font-weight:400;
    font-family:'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 80px;
}


.item {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.item {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.item-hover, .item-hover .mask, .item-img, .item-info {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.item-hover, .item-hover .mask {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
}
.item-type-double .item-hover {
    z-index:5;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    opacity:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}
.item-type-double .item-info {
    z-index:10;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:table;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
}

.item-type-double .item-info div.mycell {
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 100%;
    display:table-cell;
}
.item-type-double .item-info .headline {
    font-size:2.4em;
    font-family:'open sans';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.item-type-double .item-info .date {
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:'Canter';
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.item-type-double .item-hover .mask {
    background-color:#000;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:0;
}
.item-type-double .item-hover:hover .line {
    width:90%;
}
.item-type-double .item-hover:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
.item-img {
    width:100%;
    z-index:0;


}

body, div,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
p, blockquote, pre, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend, th, td,
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is because `img` creates a small gap due to be `display:inline` by default

so you just have to add this to your CSS:

```
.item-img img {
    display:block
}
```

a full snippet here:

```css
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.My-Gems {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
h2.Second-Header {
    color: black;
    font-weight:400;
    font-family:'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 80px;
}
.item {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.item {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.item-hover, .item-hover .mask, .item-img, .item-info {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.item-hover, .item-hover .mask {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
}
.item-type-double .item-hover {
    z-index:5;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    opacity:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}
.item-type-double .item-info {
    z-index:10;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:table;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
}
.item-type-double .item-info div.mycell {
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 100%;
    display:table-cell;
}
.item-type-double .item-info .headline {
    font-size:2.4em;
    font-family:'open sans';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.item-type-double .item-info .date {
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:'Canter';
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.item-type-double .item-hover .mask {
    background-color:#000;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:0;
}
.item-type-double .item-hover:hover .line {
    width:90%;
}
.item-type-double .item-hover:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
.item-img {
    width:100%;
    z-index:0;
}
.item-img img {
    width:100%;
    display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="My-Gems">
  <h2 class="Second-Header">Latest Works</h2>
  <div class="item item-type-double">
    <div class="item-img">
      <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/8safbuqmf/Money_Matters_Logo_gif.png " alt="" />
    </div>
    <a class="item-hover">
      <div class="item-info">
        <div class="mycell">
          <div class="date">Branding</div>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="headline">Money Matters</div>
          <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mask"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-type-double">
    <div class="item-img">
      <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/wrpgkar0n/Metaphon_Fitness.png" />
    </div>
    <a class="item-hover" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S74yj5rnvAo" target="_blank">
      <div class="item-info">
        <div class="mycell">
          <div class="date">Events</div>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="headline">Metaphon Fitness</div>
          <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mask"></div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of my-gems-->
```

Comment: Perfect, Thankyou. I was trying to figure it out for hours.